# Pushing data of table with column nvarchar to another table with column decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with multiple columns having nvarchar as dataype.I want to insert this record in another table where column datatype is  decimal how will i convert the data and insert

Comment: Use `cast` or `convert`.

Comment: `mysql`? or `sql-server`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
INSERT INTO `table` (result) VALUES (CAST('stringValue' AS DECIMAL(12,6)))
```